# Launch Google Map in Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

i'm trying to load Google Map inside Bootstrap 3 modal. Idea is that you have different buttons which opens different maps inside modal.

Problem is that after opening first modal (and closing it) second modal is not rendering map properly.

**HTML**

```
<button data-lat="40.7053111" data-lng="-74.2581861" class="btn showMap">New York</button>
<button data-lat="34.0458784" data-lng="-118.2502403" class="btn showMap">Los Angeles</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showMap').click(function() {
        mapInit($(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('lng'));
   });
});

function mapInit(lat, lng) {
    var modalElm = $('#mapModal');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var myOptions = { zoom: 10, center: myLatlng };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas')[0], myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng, map: map });

    modalElm.modal('show');
    modalElm.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
    });
}
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zpj0jefu/5/)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with the loading time after the canvas clears the first time.  If you add the class fade to your modal class then it causes a delay and loads perfectly over and over.  I revamped the fiddle a little so your map looks cleaner inside your modal by adding a new `<div id ="map-canvas">` inside your modal-body and slightly changing your css properties.  Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zpj0jefu/8/  If this helps you please make it the accepted answer.  If not, let me know and I'll see what I can do to change it for you. :)